# htaccess mod_rewrite rule for one parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can I write something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^ wordpress/?s=%1 [L]
```

I need do rewrite rule from *domain.com?s=something* to *domain.com/wordpress/?s=something*.

Folder with wordpress is by symlink but It is not interesting.

Rule what I was send works but makes error 500 on other URLs like *domain.com/something?company=1*

Thanks

Btw: I must send this "body" twice for successful validation. Wtf @stackoverflow? And why are you cut greeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need this single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ wordpress/ [L]
```

Original query string is automatically copied over.

Comment: It makes redirect to url: domain.com/wordpress/?s=test I want same URL but request must be to subfolder, right?

Comment: Try my updated rule now after clearing browser cache.